# Как убрать дублирование img?

Tags: php, изображения

Хочу сделать ссылку на файл.

```
<?php
$dir = 'img/'; // Папка с изображениями

$name = $product->title;  //название файла Nokia
$atr = $product->atr;  //расширение файла .jpg

$files = $name . $atr; // Берём всё содержимое директории

$path = $dir.$files; // Получаем путь к картинке
echo "$path"; // Выводим ссылку на картинку
```

И у меня получается такое `img/Nokiaimg.jpg`
Лишняя `img` пристыковывается..Всем спасибо

Comment: Выведите каждую переменную по отдельности, чтобы разобраться в проблеме

Comment: к переменной пристыковывается $atr = $product->atr;  img.jpg а должно просто выводить .jpg

Comment: в базе данных стоит "atr" varchar(255) utf8_general_ci   как определенно ".jpg"

Comment: Выведите КАЖДУЮ переменную по отдельности, чтобы разобраться в проблеме

Comment: все...в бд было установлено значение..убрал все исчезло..я дундук..извиняюсь за беспокойство